# Rails: render list with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button that links to a `details action` to show a list of records for a specific `reporting_date`:

```
<%= link_to "DETAILS", opportunity_details_path(:reporting_date => date), class: "btn small-bright-button hidden-xs" %>
```

However, what I want to do now is to render that list below the button in a partial with ajax rather than reloading the whole page and go to the opportunity_details view.

I suppose my button should then contain a `remote: true`:

```
<%= link_to "DETAILS", opportunity_details_path(:reporting_date => date), class: "btn small-bright-button hidden-xs", remote: true %>
```

That's were I'm stuck now.

How do I have to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Loading stuff step by step (and not loading everything at once) via ajax is great for decreasing initial load times and speed up the performance of your app. So kudos for giving it a go. Here's what you can do:

Let's say that the information inside `_details.html.erb` is wrapped around in a div called `.deails-wrapper`, so that it becomes

**_details.html.erb** (or whatever the page is called)

```
<div class="details-wrapper">
   <p> Some details about this Opportunity </p>
</div>
```

Remove:

```
<div class="details-wrapper">

<div> <!-- or whatever element is the greatest parent -->
```

And keep just the actual information inside `_details.html.erb`

```
<p> Some details about this Opportunity </p>
```

Then what you do, is put the outer-most element below your button:

```
<%= link_to "DETAILS", opportunity_details_path(:reporting_date => date), class: "btn small-bright-button hidden-xs" %>
```

Where you want the information to appear, so that it becomes

```
<%= link_to "DETAILS", opportunity_details_path(:reporting_date => date), class: "btn small-bright-button hidden-xs" %>

<div class="details-wrapper"><div> <!-- Just an empty div for now -->
```

(Don't forget to add `remote: true` to the button)

inside the controller add render `:opportunity_details`:

```
def opportunity_details
render :opportunity_details
end
```

Now create a file with the same name as the controller action, in the same folder as the `_details.html.erb` (or whatever it's called) but not a html.erb but a `js.erb` file. All the js-code inside this .`js.erb` will then be executed everytime someone clicks the button. file Do you remember the empty element we put under the button – It will work as our render-point.

**opportunity_details.js.erb**

```
$('.details-wrapper').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'path_to/details.html.erb') %>");
```

And this is basically it. You may encounter some errors due to your model not being setup to accept js requests. But all in all you're good to go!